# How to declare an object and assign its properties later

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have the example below that creates a google maps Rectangle Object. I want to only declare the Object, something like 'rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle()' and then access its properties like 'rectangle.bounds' but seem that this doesn't work

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

`bounds` is not a property, but a parameter of constructor. CMIIW.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Rectangle), you can get the `bounds` property with method `getBounds()`

This should work. I haven't tried.
`var bounds = rectangle.getBounds()`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Rectangle) the Rectangle class accepts an optional parameter of type **google.maps.RectangleOptions** This is the object which actually holds the properties like bounds, editable, and so on.

If you instantiate a new instance of Rectangle like

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

only the three properties you defined actually exist. Furthermore the **bounds** property will be undefined since it's assigned a bounds variable which does not exist.

Unfortunately Google doesn't offer a direct way to create such a RectangleOptions object.

So the proper way would be to create a new general object with all those properties available for a [RectangleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#RectangleOptions) object and feed those to the constructor of Rectangle.

```
var options = {
  bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
  clickable: true,
  draggable: false,
  editable: false,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  map: new google.maps.Map(""),
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokePosition: google.maps.StrokePosition.CENTER,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  visible: true,
  zIndex: 1
}
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(options);
console.log(rectangle.bounds);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var rectangle = {}
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            bounds: bounds,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
          });
```

try like above, pls